# URL-encode a string

Tags: python

I am able to do the following to build a url:

```
base_url = 'http://google.com/'
qs = urllib.urlencode({'q': string})
url = base_url + '?' + qs
```

Is there a way to url-encode a string? For example, I would like to be able to do:

```
url = 'http://google.com/?q=' + urlencode('this is my search'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `urllib.quote` or `urllib.quote_plus`, eg:

```
>>> urllib.quote('this is my string')
'this%20is%20my%20string'

>>> urllib.quote_plus('this is my string')
'this+is+my+string'
```